# Can I adjust the White Balance/Color Temperature (hardware) settings of my monitor?

Tags: hardware, display-manager, color-management, xset

I know that one can do quite much programatically (shell commands) to the attached monitor hardware in Linux:

- [turn it on/off (truly, hardware-wise)](https://askubuntu.com/a/7299) with `xset dpms force off`
- [toggle the brightness](http://sandipbgt.com/2015/10/01/control-screen-brightness-from-commandline-in-ubuntu/) (again, truly hardware)
- [toggling the backlight](https://askubuntu.com/a/827465)
- [change gamma](https://askubuntu.com/a/62270)

So here comes the question:

#### **Can I somehow (programatically) reach the White Balance/Color Temperature Settings of my monitor?**

I am asking specifically for Samsung PM55F-BC and PM43F-BC. ([Manuals confirm](https://heinekingmedia.de/shop/wp-content/uploads/datenblaetter/Datenblatt_PM43F-BC.pdf), there are at least options for manually doing it on the device...) We have plenty of kiosk devices and I'd rather avoid visiting each of them...